# how to get files from ~/Library folder after App Sandbox enabled?

Tags: macos, sandbox, filepath

When App Sanbox is off then i am able to get files from Library path folders. But when I does App sanbox enabled it's not accessing any files from Library folder.

Getting file from path when App Sanbox OFF

```
   NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/"];
```

What i do same when App sanbox is enabled?

Answer (score 0):

As the ["App Sandbox Design Guide"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW15) says: "...  the container includes an individual Library directory (specified by the NSLibraryDirectory search path constant) **for use only by your app** ...". This means you can't access user's 'Library' folder while using sandbox.

To resolve this you may use `NSOpenPanel` with predefined path. If end-user confirms the sheet your app will grand access to the path specefied in that sheet.